# use engine routes instead of main app(wrapper app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-engines, view-helpers

I am implementing `rails` app in which I have a `rails engine` as well.

In main app I have a model `Marks`

```
class Mark < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Rake routes for `Mark` is (simple and index page url)

```
mark_path(`)
```

Url for this `/marks/`

and inside the `engine` also there is a model `Mark`.

```
class Test::Mark < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

For `engine`

```
marks_path
```

**Url for Engine**

```
/test/marks/1
```

**Query**

So how can access `engine` `marks_path` in `engine's` model.
Currently when use the `url_helper` in model it return `main app` routes instead of `engine routes`.

But I need **`engine` routes**.